# IPerspectiveListener not called with savePerspectiveAs() , any alternative?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I am pretty new to RCP , and trying my hands on upgrading eclipse 3.x RCP application to Eclipse 4.x

With Eclipse photon, `IPerspectiveListener` is not called when saving a perspective via *Window* > *Save perspective as*.

There seems to be a bug reported with this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529999

Any alternative to `IPerspectiveListener` whenever a `savePerspectiveas()` is called, so that it allows us to add the new custom perspective to the perspective registry

As per my understanding, `savePerspectiveAs()` saves the perspective and updates `hasCustomDefinition` to true and publishes a `UIEvent` with the topic name `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.PERSPECTIVE_SAVED`.

I tried subscribing to the above publish event but was not successful.

Comment: `WorkbenchPage.savePerspectiveAs` definitely publishes a `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.PERSPECTIVE_SAVED` event and it is used by various things such as `MinMaxAddon`. How are you subscribing to that event?

Comment: I tried with  @Inject  
   eventbroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.PERSPECTIVE_SAVED, new eventhandler).   But this doesn't seem to get triggered  when publishevent was executed  in savePerspectiveAs method

Comment: [edit] your question and add properly formatted code.